# How can I leverage browser cache for minified JS or minified CS files?

Tags: javascript, htaccess, cache

I am absolutely comfortable utilizing HTACCESS but I am working on speed load. I have a minified JS file. How would I go about adding this into my HTACCESS?

Below I was going to add this line to htaccess to leverage browser cache for minified JS file.

```
    ExpiresByType application/js.min A31536000
```

Comment: Plz elaborate the problem

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can do leverage browser caching for minified js & css files same as we do for other files.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"  
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

You are talking about speed, for that you can add gzip or deflate in htaccess.